# Double integral over triangle, what bounds should be chosen?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

### Question

In an exercise, I am supposed to evaluate the integral
$$
\iint_D(x -y)e^{x+y}
$$
where $D$ is the triangle with the three corner points $(0,0)$, $(0,2)$ and $(2,2)$.

I tried computing
$$
\int_0^2\int_0^x f(x,y)~dydx
$$
and I got the given correct answer, **but** with the opposite sign eg. $(-1)\cdot$*the correct answer*. This can  happen when the bounds are flipped for an integral as can be seen in [this S.E question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786765/negative-sign-that-appears-in-integration) for example. Have I flipped on any of the bounds? It seems to me, that these are the obvious bounds to choose.

You can see my solution below, if this is not the problem.

### My solution

$$
\begin{align}
f &= (x-y)e^{x+y}\\
\iint_D f~dydx &= \int_0^2\int_0^x f~dydx\\
\int_0^x f~dy &= \left[(x-y)e^{x+y} + e^{x+y} \right]_0^x\\ &= e^{2x} - xe^x - e^x\\
\Rightarrow \int_0^2\int_0^x f(x,y)~dydx &= \left[\frac{e^{2x}}{2} - xe^x \color{grey}{+e^x - e^x} \right]_0^x\\
= e^4/2 - 2e^2 - 1/2 &=\frac{1}{2}(e^4 - 4e^2 - 1)
\end{align}
$$
It's supposed to be $-1/2(e^4 - 4e^2 - 1)$. I have double checked with [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E2%5Cint_0%5Ex%20((x-y)e%5E(x%2By))dydx) and it seems that my calculation of the integral is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the region $D$, $x\leqslant y\leqslant 2$, so the limits for $y$ should be $x$ and $2$ rather than $0$ and $x$. With your limits, you are finding the integral over the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (2,0)$ and $(2,2)$.

Comment: Wow, you're right... I can't believe I missed that. I've even drawn a figure of it with $(2,0)$ instead of $(0,2)$!

Answer (score 1):

The triangle you are integrating over has vertices $(0,0),(0,2)$ and $(2,2)$. Now what this geometrically means, is that you integrate over the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|0\leq x,y\leq2\;and\;y\geq x\}$. Make a sketch if you do not see this directly, but it is not very hard to see this. This has the implication, however that we should integrate with respect to $y$ not from $0$ to $x$ but from $x$ to $2$ (Since $x\geq y\geq 2$). With these new boundaries, your integral should give the right result.